# Choosing between Present Continuous and Present Simple for an action taking place right now

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

Is there any rule in English regulating how I should choose between Present Continuous and Present Simple when I refer to the things happening at the moment?

For example:

(interrogation scene, a police investigator is talking to a suspect or a victim)

> So, on one hand, **you are saying** that your car was stolen two days
> ago, but on the other hand, **you also say** that you drove back home
> last night on your own car. How is that possible? Can you clear it up
> for me, please?

Here the first "say" is in Present Continuous and the second one is in Present Simple despite the fact that both "sayings" are taking place right now, that is, at the time of speaking. Do I need to put both in Present Continuous to be consistent or keeping it the way it is is fine? If yes, then why not first Present Simple and then Present Continuous?

The wiki pages that I've looked through:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_present

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_continuous

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_tense

provide a lot of useful information on how these tenses differ in their usage, but they don't provide any clue on which one of those tenses to choose when they refer to exactly the same situation.

Also, I know that such verbs like "say", "think", "see", "feel" are often used in Present Simple form when they can be used in Present Continuous, but still I've heard native speakers using them in Present Continuous, too. They must be following some "inner sense" that every native speaker has. But is there any rule or guidance to follow in order to help a non-native speaker that doesn't have that kind of native "inner sense"?

Comment: In the police interview, it wouldn't be wrong to use _say_ in both cases. The continuous tense just emphasises the fact that the interviewee _continues_ to assert that a particular version of events is the truth.

Comment: The cited text just *happens* to use Continuous for the first highlighted instance, and Simple Present for the second. But it could just as well have been the other way around, OR they could both be Continuous, OR they could both be Simple Present. Which particular stylistic choices were made in this respect would make ***no difference whatsoever*** to the meaning of the text. So you might as well think of it as ***random choices***.